# Statistical Quality Control Macro Changing parameters to a determined std.dev

Tags: vba, excel

I found a macro online that creates a Statistical Quality Control chart online. So I have a .Csv file that looks like an excel sheet. I use the macro, so I have to select the data points. Then I have to select the labels, and then it gets plotted.

So instead of calculating the standard deviation from the selected data as my macro does, I want it to calculate the Upper limits and Lower limits from a set Standard deviation. Which is in the cell "F3". I have tried creating a variant where "stddev=Range("F3").value" But when I included it in my macro, the data was scattered and my labels on the right were not showing up as they were before. I will specify , where in the code that I think the problem is lying.

Here is the full code for creating the Quality control chart:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Function GetRange(box_message As String) As Range
        Set GetRange = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set GetRange = Application.InputBox(box_message, "Select Range", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
    End Function

    Public Function IsNotOk(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean 'TO CHECK IF A GIVEN RANGE IS BLANK
        IsNotOk = True
        On Error GoTo if_error_occured:
        If rng.Rows.Count > 0 And rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then IsNotOk = False
    if_error_occured:
        If Err.Number Then IsNotOk = True
    End Function

    Public Function check_if_numeric(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim cel As Range
    check_if_numeric = True
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(cel.Value)) Then check_if_numeric = False
    Next cel
    End Function

    Sub Make_Control_Chart()
        Dim data_values As Range
        Dim chart_labels As Range
        Dim range_selected_before As Range
        Dim got_label_range As Boolean
        Dim got_value_range As Boolean
        Dim bActivate As Boolean
        Dim myChtObj As ChartObject
        Dim plot_series, MyNewSrs As Series
        Dim series_label As String
        Dim number_of_control_limits As Integer
        Dim standard_deviation As Integer
        Dim data_str As String
        Dim avg_str As String

        Dim stddev As Variant

        On Error GoTo if_error_occured: 'GOTO THE END OF THE PROGRAM


        stddev = Range("F3").Value

        'GET RANGE FOR DATA VALUES
        bActivate = False   ' True to re-activate the input range
        Set data_values = GetRange("Please select the range containing the DATA POINTS" & Chr(13) & "(press select a single column)")
        If IsNotOk(data_values) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect Input Data !"
            End
        ElseIf Not (check_if_numeric(data_values)) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect Input Data !"
            End
        End If

        'GET RANGE FOR CHART X-AXIS LABELS
        got_label_range = True   ' True to re-activate the input range
        Set chart_labels = GetRange("Please select the range containing the LABELS" & Chr(13) & "(press ESC if no labels available)")
        If IsNotOk(chart_labels) Then
            got_label_range = False
        End If


        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual



        'LETS CREATE THE CHART NOW
        Set myChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Width:=450, Top:=25, Height:=300)
        myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers


        'REMOVE ALL UNWANTED SERIES FROM CHART, IF ANY
        For Each MyNewSrs In myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection ' myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
            MyNewSrs.Delete
        Next MyNewSrs
        Set MyNewSrs = Nothing


        If got_label_range Then 'IF WE HAVE THE LABEL RANGE
        'ADD NEW SERIES
            Set MyNewSrs = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With MyNewSrs
                .Name = "PLOT"
                .Values = data_values
                .XValues = chart_labels.Value
            End With
        Else
            Set MyNewSrs = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With MyNewSrs
                .Name = "PLOT"
                .Values = data_values
            End With
        End If

        'FORMAT THE PLOT SERIES
        Set plot_series = MyNewSrs
        With MyNewSrs
            .Border.ColorIndex = 1
            .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 2
            .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .MarkerStyle = xlCircle
            .Smooth = False
            .MarkerSize = 5
            .Shadow = False
        End With
        Set MyNewSrs = Nothing





        'CREATE NAMED RANGE FOR THE DATA VALUES, AVERAGE, LOWER AND UPPER CONTROL LIMITS

        data_str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_data_values"
        avg_str = "roundup(average(" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_data_values" & "),2)"

'HERE THE LIMITS ARE SET AND THE ORIGINAL CODE IS SET IN THERE WHERE IT WORKS ON A SET OF DATA POINTS, HOWEVER WHEN I TRY TO CHANGE IT TO JUST "1*stddev,3" the data gets all scattered. I'M WONDERING WHY THE DATA IS BEING SCATTERED?

        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_data_values", RefersToR1C1:=data_values
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_AVG", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & ""
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_LCL1", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(1*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_LCL2", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(2*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_LCL3", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(3*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_UCL1", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(1*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_UCL2", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(2*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_UCL3", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(3*stdev(" & data_str & "),3)"
```

The code for formatting and creating the lines on the chart:

```
        'ADD THE LINE FOR AVERAGE
    Set MyNewSrs = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    With MyNewSrs
        .Name = "AVG = "
        .Values = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_AVG"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        '.ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlNone, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=10000
        '.ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlUp, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=20
        .ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlPlusValues, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=data_values.Rows.Count
        .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .MarkerStyle = xlNone
        .Smooth = False
        .MarkerSize = 5
        .Shadow = False
        With .Border
            .Weight = xlHairline
            .LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
        'With .ErrorBars.Border
        '    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        '    .ColorIndex = 3
        '    .Weight = xlThin
        'End With
    End With



    Set MyNewSrs = Nothing

    'ADD UPPER AND LOWER CONTROL LIMITS
     For number_of_control_limits = 1 To 3
        For standard_deviation = -1 To 1 Step 2

            Select Case standard_deviation:
                Case -1: series_label = "LCL"
                Case 1: series_label = "UCL"
            End Select

            Set MyNewSrs = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With MyNewSrs
                .Name = series_label & number_of_control_limits & " ="
                .Values = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_" & series_label & number_of_control_limits
                .ChartType = xlXYScatter
                .ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlPlusValues, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=data_values.Rows.Count
            End With

            MyNewSrs.ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlPlusValues, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=data_values.Rows.Count

            Select Case number_of_control_limits:
                Case 1:
                            With MyNewSrs.ErrorBars.Border
                                .LineStyle = xlGray25
                                .ColorIndex = 15
                                .Weight = xlHairline
                            End With
                Case 2:
                            With MyNewSrs.ErrorBars.Border
                                .LineStyle = xlGray25
                                .ColorIndex = 57
                                .Weight = xlHairline
                            End With
                Case 3:
                            With MyNewSrs.ErrorBars.Border
                                .LineStyle = xlGray75
                                .ColorIndex = 3
                                .Weight = xlHairline
                            End With
            End Select

            MyNewSrs.ErrorBars.EndStyle = xlNoCap

            With MyNewSrs
                With .Border
                    .Weight = xlHairline
                    .LineStyle = xlNone
                End With
                .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .MarkerStyle = xlNone
                .Smooth = False
                .MarkerSize = 5
                .Shadow = False
            End With
            Set MyNewSrs = Nothing
        Next standard_deviation
    Next number_of_control_limits

   myChtObj.Chart.ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False, _
        HasLeaderLines:=False, ShowSeriesName:=True, ShowCategoryName:=False, _
        ShowValue:=True, ShowPercentage:=False, ShowBubbleSize:=False, Separator:=" "

    'OFFSET THE LABELS
    For Each MyNewSrs In myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        With MyNewSrs.Points(1).DataLabel
            .Left = 400
        End With
    Next MyNewSrs


    'LETS FORMAT THE CHART
    With myChtObj
        With .Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
            .MajorTickMark = xlNone
            .MinorTickMark = xlNone
            .TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis
        End With
        With .Chart.Axes(xlValue)
            .MajorTickMark = xlOutside
            .MinorTickMark = xlNone
            .TickLabelPosition = xlNextToAxis
        End With
        With .Chart.ChartArea.Border
            .Weight = 1
            .LineStyle = 0
        End With
        With .Chart.PlotArea.Border
            .ColorIndex = 1
            .Weight = xlThin
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
        With .Chart.PlotArea.Interior
            .ColorIndex = 2
            .PatternColorIndex = 1
            .Pattern = xlSolid
        End With
        With .Chart.ChartArea.Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 8
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Background = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With .Chart
            .HasTitle = False
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Control Chart"
            .ChartTitle.Left = 134
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Observations"
        End With
        With .Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels
            .Alignment = xlCenter
            .Offset = 100
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .Orientation = xlHorizontal
        End With
    End With



    myChtObj.Chart.Legend.Delete
    myChtObj.Chart.PlotArea.Width = 310
    myChtObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
    myChtObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = myChtObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale
    myChtObj.Chart.ChartArea.Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    myChtObj.Chart.ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = True


    'DELETE THE LABELS FOR THE ACTUAL DATA SERIES
    plot_series.DataLabels.Delete
    Set plot_series = Nothing

if_error_occured:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    If Err.Number Then z_delete_all_named_range

End Sub


Sub z_delete_all_named_range()
Dim nam As Name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    For Each nam In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    nam.Delete
    Next nam
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably too much code in this question

Comment: @TimWilliams I cut the code down a little. Some functions i kept because they are part of setting the limits. Sorry about that .

Answer (score 0):

Compiled but not tested:

```
Sub Make_Control_Chart()
        Dim data_values As Range
        Dim chart_labels As Range
        Dim range_selected_before As Range
        Dim got_label_range As Boolean
        Dim got_value_range As Boolean
        Dim bActivate As Boolean
        Dim myChtObj As ChartObject
        Dim plot_series, MyNewSrs As Series
        Dim series_label As String
        Dim number_of_control_limits As Integer
        Dim standard_deviation As Integer
        Dim data_str As String
        Dim avg_str As String


        Dim stddev As Variant
        Dim wb As Workbook, sCht As String, i As Long

        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

        'On Error GoTo if_error_occured: 'GOTO THE END OF THE PROGRAM

        stddev = Range("F3").Value

        'GET RANGE FOR DATA VALUES
        bActivate = False   ' True to re-activate the input range
        Set data_values = GetRange("Please select the range containing the DATA POINTS" & _
                                   Chr(13) & "(press select a single column)")
        If IsNotOk(data_values) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect Input Data !"
            Exit Sub 'not End!
        ElseIf Not (check_if_numeric(data_values)) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect Input Data !"
            Exit Sub 'not End!
        End If

        'GET RANGE FOR CHART X-AXIS LABELS
        got_label_range = True   ' True to re-activate the input range
        Set chart_labels = GetRange("Please select the range containing the LABELS" & _
                                   Chr(13) & "(press ESC if no labels available)")
        If IsNotOk(chart_labels) Then
            got_label_range = False
        End If


        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        'LETS CREATE THE CHART NOW
        Set myChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Width:=450, _
                                                    Top:=25, Height:=300)
        myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers


        'REMOVE ALL UNWANTED SERIES FROM CHART, IF ANY
        For Each MyNewSrs In myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
            MyNewSrs.Delete
        Next MyNewSrs
        Set MyNewSrs = Nothing


         'IF WE HAVE THE LABEL RANGE
        'ADD NEW SERIES
        Set MyNewSrs = myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With MyNewSrs
            .Name = "PLOT"
            .Values = data_values
            If got_label_range Then
                .XValues = chart_labels.Value
            End If
        End With


        'FORMAT THE PLOT SERIES
        Set plot_series = MyNewSrs
        With MyNewSrs
            .Border.ColorIndex = 1
            .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 2
            .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .MarkerStyle = xlCircle
            .Smooth = False
            .MarkerSize = 5
            .Shadow = False
        End With
        Set MyNewSrs = Nothing

        'CREATE NAMED RANGE FOR THE DATA VALUES, AVERAGE, LOWER AND UPPER CONTROL LIMITS
        sCht = sCht
        data_str = sCht & "_data_values"
        avg_str = "roundup(average(" & sCht & "_data_values" & "),2)"


        wb.Names.Add Name:=sCht & "_data_values", RefersToR1C1:=data_values
        wb.Names.Add Name:=sCht & "_AVG", RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & ""

        For i = 1 To 3

            wb.Names.Add Name:=sCht & "_LCL" & i, _
                RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "- roundup(" & i & "*" & stddev & ",3)"
            wb.Names.Add Name:=sCht & "_UCL" & i, _
                RefersToR1C1:="=" & avg_str & "+ roundup(" & i & "*" & stddev & ",3)"
        Next i

End Sub

Public Function GetRange(box_message As String) As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetRange = Application.InputBox(box_message, "Select Range", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
End Function

Public Function IsNotOk(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean 'TO CHECK IF A GIVEN RANGE IS BLANK
    IsNotOk = True
    On Error GoTo if_error_occured:
    If rng.Rows.Count > 0 And rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then IsNotOk = False
if_error_occured:
    If Err.Number Then IsNotOk = True
End Function

Public Function check_if_numeric(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim cel As Range, rv As Boolean
    rv = True
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(cel.Value)) Then
            rv = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cel
    check_if_numeric = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @TimWilliams! I tried this code and indeed, it does plot! However, when I added my code for formatting the lines and such. I received an error at this line for some reason:    .Values = "='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(myChtObj.Name, " ", "") & "_AVG"
. The error was object not defined. I wasn't sure why the Average line is not created?

Comment: Update your question to add your current code, and indicate where you get the error.